# Supervisord Restart Wait Until Execution Completes

Tags: ubuntu-16.04, configure, supervisord

How can I configure supervisord to wait for a program to complete before restarting it?

When I call restart I want supervisord to start the program if it is not running. If it is running, I want to wait for the program execution to complete and then start the program.

Comment: It might help if you mention your OS (with version) ...

Comment: Ubuntu 16.04 using Supervisor 3.3.1-1 (current latest in apt yakkety repo)